# Convert rostopic pub into c++ code

Tags: arduino, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do i convert a rostopic pub command and run it in a C++ script?
I would like to pub the gripper angle when i state the position of the robot arm but i cant seam to control the gripper.

```
rostopic pub gripper_angle std_msgs/UInt16 0-180
```

Where the 0-180 is the angles and you edit the angle of the gripper you want it to be. Normally the rostopic pub is sent from the terminal. The c++ script will be run from the terminal which will be run using rosrun.

I hope yoou guys can help me. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355576/convert-rostopic-pub-into-c++-code/) by [Calvin](https://answers.ros.org/users/55955/calvin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer to the question you asked is below. *However* I think there is a hidden question here. What have you tried so far to make a publisher in C++ and what happened when it didn't work?

---

Take a look at [the tutorial for writing a publisher in C++](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2FTutorials.2FWritingPublisherSubscriber.Writing_the_Publisher_Node).

You will need to make the following changes:

1. Change the name of the node on line 47 to something more appropriate for what you are doing, e.g. `"gripper_controller"`
2. Change the topic name on line 73 to be the topic you want to publish to, in this case `"gripper_angle"`.
3. Change the header file on line 28 to the data type you want to publish, which is `"std_msgs/UInt16.h"`
4. Change the type of the `Publisher` on line 73 to be `UInt16`.
5. Remove the `while` loop and have it just publish data once, with the value you want to publish. If you are trying to make a utility you can call from the command line with an argument, then you should get that value from a command line argument. There are plenty of tutorials on the web about how to parse command line arguments in C++.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2020-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Calvin](https://answers.ros.org/users/55955/calvin/) on 2020-06-23**:
i have coded this but there is not echo from the function clodeGripper().

```
  ros::NodeHandle node_handle;
  ros::Publisher gripper_angle = node_handle.advertise<std_msgs::UInt16>("angle", 10);
  std_msgs::UInt16 msg;
  msg.data = 180;
  gripper_angle.publish(msg);
```

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2020-06-23**:
Please post your complete code, and if there is an error output when compiling it or running it, post that as well. Use a GitHub Gist if it's long.

**Comment by [Calvin](https://answers.ros.org/users/55955/calvin/) on 2020-06-23**:
Maybe I can redirect you here,
https://answers.ros.org/question/355611/publish-from-ros-cpp-to-arduino/

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2020-06-23**:\

- That question duplicates this one, with different wording and a little different information. Please do not do that.
- That question still doesn't include your entire source.

**Comment by [Calvin](https://answers.ros.org/users/55955/calvin/) on 2020-06-23**:
I am sorry for the mistake that I have made. I am new to posting questions online and asking for help. this is the link to both the files of the publisher and the subscriber for the question above.

https://github.com/MojoZuikie/eti_moveit.git

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2020-06-24**:
The problem is that you are creating a publisher in the `closeGripper()` and `openGripper()` functions, using that to publish a message, then exiting the function. It is likely that the publisher is being cleaned up by going out of scope before it even has a chance to publish the message, and even if it publishes the message it probably does so before any subscribers listening to that topic get connected to the publisher. You need  to create a single publisher for the topic once in your node's set up, then use that throughout.

**Comment by [Calvin](https://answers.ros.org/users/55955/calvin/) on 2020-06-25**:
I found out a way to control the gripper using the code above. Thanks Very much.